# How to reduce this code to be faster?

Tags: python, performance

This is my code in python:

```
def Problem12():
    i = 0
    a = 0
    c = 1
    while True:
        i2 = 1
        i += 1
        while True:
            if(tNum(i)%i2 == 0):
                c += 1
            if(c == 5):
                return tNum(i)
            if(i2 == tNum(i)):
                i += 1
                i2 = 0
                c = 0
            i2 += 1
    def tNum(stop):
        i = 0
        a = 0
        while True:
            i += 1
            a += i
            if(i == stop):
                return a
    print ">| Your answer is:",Problem12()
```

Output:

```
>| Your answer is: 28
```

If you can run it, it will throw the answer fast but if we change:

```
if(c == 500):
    return tNum(i)
```

This will take a long time to calculate than desired. My goal is to learn how to better analyze this code and how to reduce computation resources.

Comment: what you trying to do here, plz put the question too and expected output

Comment: i assume this is project euler problem 12?  it would help if you had more meaningful names, comments, etc.

Answer (score 1):

One immediate advance I can see is:

> Hint:
>
> There is a simple arithmetical formula that gives the nth triangle number.

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about Project Euler 12,

you should firstly change the stopping condition to be more than 500, as the problem says "over five hundred divisors".
Do not iterate over all numbers and check if they are triangular. Generate triangular numbers and check, how many divisors it has. Generating triangular numbers is easy, just look at the pattern.
Checking if a number is a divisor can be done in O(sqrt(n)), just find how many numbers are till sqrt(n), and multiply by 2 (edge condition if the number is a squre).
This should make your program run fast enough